# Python: While loop unending

Tags: python

I am trying to get a conditioned while with or statements for an assignment for a game programming class. I am trying to use a loop something like this. They are not exactly like this, but it is the same conditions for the while statement.

```
tempstr = input("Type B ")
while tempstr != "B" or tempstr != "b":
     tempstr = input("Type anything ")
```

I have also tried.

```
tempstr = input("Type B ")
while tempstr == "B" or tempstr == "b":
     tempstr = input("Type anything ")
```

As well as.

```
 while tempstr == "B" or tempstr == "b":
      tempstr = input("Type anything ")
```

I've checked that tempstr is set to B or b, and they still continue to ask for an input instead of just ending the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
While True:
    tempstr = input("Type anything ")
    if tempstr.lower()  == 'b':
        break
```

Comment: Why would we want to add a `while True` wrapper and break out of it when we already know the condition that should trigger the while to break?

Comment: @sberry if it's a game then the OP might need to check for other inputs as well

Comment: That does work. Thank you. Guess I need to rethink my code, and not make this same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> From your question, i have understood that you want to get out of the
> program whenever B letter is typed and we can make it possible bye
> just using simple if statement.

Try this,

```
while True:    
  tempstr = input("Type B ")
  if tempstr == "B" or tempstr == "b":
    break


Type B d
Type B e
Type B g
Type B b
```